# Vue IE Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue application, it is working fine in Mac OS Chrome, Safari, Windows Chrome. When I am using Internet Explorer, the app is loading fine but the moment I click on a button to hit the api call, it says

> Unhandled Promise Rejection ReferenceError: 'Request' is undefined.

I have checked my front end code, and I can not see if I have used `Request` anywhere in my code.

Did anyone have faced any such issue? Let me know if you want the axios interceptor code or the api call code.

Comment: Which version ie are you using?

Comment: @Grzesiek I am on IE11.

Comment: Promise polyfill does not work in IE11. But that's OK, because nobody uses IE 11, except developers and website owners who, for no particular reason, want to know if their product works in IE11. If you want your axios requests to be compatible with IE11, you have an example in this thread: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1694. Also note you can't use async/await in IE11, afaik.